被诈骗者 诈骗所有ada虚拟资产
你好，cardano官方, 我被截图中的youtuber（诈骗者）冒充cardano CEO的诈骗者诈骗了我的所有ada虚拟资产，原本我是不相信的，可是当我看到了神似Charles Hoskinson大神的在直播，于是我相信了，那是我仅有的全部资产，希望官方能够从技术角度协助我找回我的资产，由衷的感谢




Sorry, we aren't a recovery service.

Hi, I'm sorry to hear what happened to you. We are no "Cardano officials" but a community forum. These type of scams are always on the rise when interest in cryptocurrencies increases. Unfortunately there's little you can do except for working with your local authorities.

诈骗者的钱包地址：stake1u8ll2l7yqpsmsys8zn3gh5xn95fhpusdeahdchasl3xgfqqpt3w48，


我已经联系了我当地警方、以及交易所平台方、youtube方，他们都愿意协助我找回资产，我来提供证明 恳请你们通过技术层面或者更高层面帮助我，找回我的个人虚拟资产，由衷的感谢！
